# Stop elements in a div from positioning elsewhere when they should fit in the div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div, which I have 2 input fields and a button inside with the same height as the parent div (30 px), but somehow they are positioned outside of the width and height I set for the parent div.

this is what it looks like currently, which is not what I want at all

[image: example]

(don't mind the pink box at the top and the pink button at the bottom)

Here is the codepen for reference: https://codepen.io/lanadelrey13/pen/dyQgzXE

I tried using `margin`, `padding`, `whitespace: nowrap;`, `box-sizing`, and one or two other things which I don't remember. None of them worked.

```css
.container {
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-row;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "martian-mono-variable", sans-serif;
}

.ersatzButton {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #e7c786;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
}

.textBox {
  width: calc(100% - 90px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-indent: 5px;
}

.fileInput {
  display: none;
}

.sendButton {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #e7c786;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/waj8csr.css">
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" class="fileInput" id="fileInput">
  
  <button class="ersatzButton" onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-file-earmark-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M8 6.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V11a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V9.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z" />
      <path d="M14 4.5V14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h5.5L14 4.5zm-3 0A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9.5 3V1H4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.5h-2z" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  
  <input type="text" class="textBox" placeholder="type here...">
  <button class="sendButton"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're required to show code _here_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 display properties set on your container

```css
.container {
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-row;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "martian-mono-variable", sans-serif;
}
```

I just changed it to `display: flex;` and it worked? I guess that's what you wanted right. If I'm not wrong `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` is used to create a table using CSS.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much I didn't even see that 